# Get reference to itemId in Extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a Window class like this:

```
Ext.define('EMS.tf.alerts.alerts.view.AlertWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.ems-alerts-window',
    height: 220,
    width: 600,
    alertTpl: undefined,
    autoScroll: true,
    selectedRecord: undefined,
    title: undefined,
    atext: undefined,

    // @private
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(me, {
            tpl: me.alertTpl,
            listeners: {
            show: function() {
                Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
                    renderTo: 'alertContainer',
                    itemId: 'buttonContainer',
                    items   : [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            cls: 'ackbtn',
                            text : 'Acknowledge',
                            name: 'ackButton',
                            itemId: 'renderbutton'
                        },{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            cls: 'attchmntbtn',
                            text : 'Attachment',
                            name: 'attButton',
                            itemId: 'renderattachmntbutton'
                        }]
                    });
                }
            },          
            title: me.title
        });
        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

I want to get reference to button "Attachment" using itemId "renderattachmntbutton". How to do this?

I tried windowobject.down('#renderattachmntbutton') but still it didn't work. I can get reference to the items placed before init function but not like this. Any idea on what needs to be done to get reference to this button?

Comment: Read the docs for `renderTo`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=renderattachmntbutton]')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

That button is not an item (a child) of the window but of the button container. If you want to find it with down then you need to grab a reference to the container and call down on that.

Instead of

```
windowobject.down('#renderattachmntbutton') // WRONG
```

call

```
buttoncontainer.down('#renderattachmntbutton') // Correct
```

Comment: But how to get a reference to "buttoncontainer"? Its an itemId to the container

Comment: Well, I would never code it like that because it too much depends on HTML that Ext is abstracting from. If buttons would be direct items of the window (recommended) then your original code would work.

Answer (score 1):

The itemId can be used with the getComponent() call on parent items, like container and panels. If you change your itemId on your container to just an id property. You can then get to your child items like so:

```
Ext.getCmp('buttonContainer').getComponent('renderattachmntbutton');
```

This is just one possible way, there are others!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I open the window again, then I will get uncaught exception as it is trying to register the same id 'buttonContainer'. This is the reason I want to use only itemIds

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
windowobject.down('[itemId=renderattachmntbutton]') ;
```

Comment: Tried that too but of no luck